# withdraw() method for a java currency exchange

Tags: java, methods

I am having trouble with this section of a project. The basic idea is to have a program as a user with a withdraw amount and then update the total balance. I was trying to do it using a switch statement. I dont understand how to do this with while keeping the dataType boolean

```
public static boolean withdraw(double amount, int currencyType) {

    double withdrawAmount = 0; 
    switch (currencyType){
    case 1: withdrawAmount = balance - amount;
    }

    updateBalance(getBalance() + convertCurrency(amount, currencyType, true));

    System.out.print(withdrawAmount);

    return false;

    //TODO: implementation here
}

//my deposit method//

public static boolean deposit(double amount, int currencyType) {    
    if(amount <= 0){

        return false;
    }

    String currency = "";
    switch (currencyType){
    case 1: currency = "U.S. Dollars"; break;
    case 2: currency = "Euros"; break;
    case 3: currency = "British Pounds"; break;
    case 4: currency = "Indian Rupees"; break;
    case 5: currency = "Australian Dollars"; break;
    case 6: currency = "Canadian Dollars"; break;
    case 7: currency = "Singapore Dollars"; break;
    case 8: currency = "Swiss Francs"; break;
    case 9: currency = "Malaysian Ringgits"; break;
    case 10: currency = "Japanese Yen"; break;
    case 11: currency = "Chinese Yuan Renminbi"; break;     
    default: return false;
    }

    updateBalance(getBalance() + convertCurrency(amount, currencyType, true));

    System.out.println("You successfully deposited " + amount + " " + currency);
    System.out.print("\n\n");

    return true;
```

Comment: "while keeping the dataType boolean" which `dataType`? There's no mention in your question of a dataType? Edit your question, it's unclear what you ask.

Comment: what i meant was this method must return a boolean value.

Comment: this is how i did my depost() method but im stuck when it comes to withdraw.

Comment: Edit your question, please. Still unclear what the returned type has to do with a `switch`...

Comment: ok. i need help figuring out who to make a withdraw() method. i posted my deposit() method to show you what it looks like. but im stuck when it comes to making a withdraw from my balance.

Comment: Well, the withdrawal is just like a deposit but instead od addind to the account you subtract.  You only need to check if the current balance is high enough and, if not, return `false` early.

Comment: I cant get it to work when i simple change the + to a -.

Comment: Your question is unclear. *Why* do you need to keep it boolean? There are a number of possible reasons. Is this homework? Are you required to return a boolean from the method, and not make it void? It seems like you want to return `true` if the withdrawal was a success and `false` if not, but I could be wrong. Please give more information; you specifically ask for "how to keep the dataType boolean" but I'm not 100% sure how to help you with that, because I'm not 100% sure what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Withdrawal amount should be converted to the account currency first, similar to how you have converted it in the deposit.

You should then check whether there would be sufficient balance;  if not, return false.

Lastly, update the balance & return true.

I'll give you a cleaner example.

```
public static boolean withdraw (double nominatedAmount, Currency nominatedCurrency) {    
    if (nominatedAmount > 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // convert to Account Currency.
    double convertedAmount = convertCurrency( nominatedAmount, nominatedCurrency, this.accountCurrency);

    // withdraw;
    //     -- checking for Sufficient Funds first.
    double outcomeBalance = getBalance() - convertedAmount;
    if (outcomeBalance  < 0) {
        return false;  // insufficient funds.
    }
    setBalance( outcomeBalance);
    log.info("withdrawal successful: acct={}, balance={}", this.accountNumber, outcomeBalance);

    // done;  success.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: First line of the method: you are checking against the value of `amount`, which is not defined. You used `nominatedAmount` instead.

Comment: it must keep the  public static boolean withdraw(double amount, int currencyType) {

Comment: Thanks Ian. And @Andronik -- Yes, but I'm more interested in showing you good practice than doing your exact homework for you. Learn.

Comment: i probably should have posted an update but this is the code that i  got after a bit of thinking it over. it passes all the test cases that i need it to pass. thanks for the help.

Comment: @Andronik,  post your proposed code as a subsection of your question -- don't overwrite this answer. BTW, the code in your proposed edit is repetitive & didn't appear to return 'false' if balance was insufficient. I would grade your submission (very) poorly if I were the teacher -- I suggest you read my example code & think a bit more about this.